# Whitelisted sites! how to obtain?

Tags: url

Iam writing a program to check if the site is in the whitelist or not? where can i obtain such a list of whitelisted urls  ?

Comment: What do you mean by whitelist?  You'll have to be more specific about what you want a whitelist of?  Virus free sites?  Non-phishing sites? etc?

Comment: a site which u can completely trust and browse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a whitelist approach, may I suggest a blacklist approach using [StopBadWare.org](http://stopbadware.org/). You can do a query against their database to determine if a url has been reported as containing malware/spyware/badware/viruses. Google provides an [API for this purpose](http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/).